# Add root element to response model

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, rest

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core API, which should follow an existing format.

The response should always start with a data element in the json

```
{
    "data": {
        "batch_id": null,
        "created_at": "2019-01-29T16:58:04+00:00",
        "current_operation": null,
        "description": "This watch has a new name",
        "model": {
            "brand_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I created a class `Batch` which contains all the properties that we see, and my controller is taking care of serialize it in the background.

```
public class Batch
{
     [JsonProperty("label")]
     public string Label { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("serial_number")]
     public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
```

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Batch> Get(string id)
{
     ...
     return batch;
}
```

Is there a way to write something so that every payload has to start with a `data` property?

I would like to avoid writing a class `DataWrapper<T>` that I have to use for every response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use an anonymous object to wrap the response from the controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Batch> Get(string id)
{
    ...
    return Ok(new { data = batch });
}
```

Comment: Woaw this is so easy to apply, thank you it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GenericClass

```
public class GenericResponseClass<T>{
    public T data;
}
```

then you can pass your batch(or any other) class to GenericResposneClass just like

```
public class Batch
{
     [JsonProperty("label")]
     public string Label { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("serial_number")]
     public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

GenericResponseClass<Batch> response = new GenericResponseClass<Batch>();
Batch batch = new Batch();
batch.Label = "New Label";
batch.SerialNumber = "Serial Number";
response.data = batch;
```

then pass/serialize your **response**